# Keep ShellExecuteExW's command prompt opened

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, winapi, shellexecute

I'm trying to use `ShellExecuteExW` to run a bat file.
I want the command prompt to be kept opened after the bat file has been executed.

Here's what I tried,

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFOW TempInfo = { 0 };

TempInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOA);
TempInfo.fMask = 0;
TempInfo.hwnd = NULL;
TempInfo.lpVerb = L"runas";
TempInfo.lpFile = L"cmd.exe";
TempInfo.lpParameters = L"\\k runMe.bat StartTool";
TempInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
TempInfo.nShow = SW_NORMAL;

::ShellExecuteExW(&TempInfo);
```

But what I see is my `cmd.exe` stays opened but it didn't actually ran my `runMe.bat` file.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using CreateProcess here

Comment: The command line flag should be `/k` instead of `\\k`

Comment: Extract from `cmd /?` states: `/K  Carries out the command specified by string but remains`

Answer (score 0):

@dewaffled answered it... `/k` instead of `\\k`